# My string padding function in C does not work?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, padding

I had tried to do it myself but failed (I am tempted to do it again for learning but just need it for an example program). Essentially I wish to represent a binary number but padded of course to the nearest byte with `0`'s so I found a function on another question here:

```
char * string_pad(char * string, size_t padlen, char * pad) {
    size_t lenstring = strlen(string);
    size_t lenpad = strlen(pad);

    char * padded = (char*)malloc(lenstring + lenpad + 1);
    strncpy(padded, string, lenstring); /* copy without '\0' */
    padded += lenstring; /* prepare for first append of pad */
    for(padlen += 1; padlen > 0; padlen--, padded += lenpad)
        strncpy(padded, pad, lenpad);
    *padded = '\0';
    return padded;
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
printf("Test: %s\n", string_pad(dec2bin(~myInt), 32, "0"));
```

Unfortunately it prints "Test: " but nothing else. My `dec2bin` returns a simple char pointer by the way if you need to know.

What seems to be causing it to do nothing?

Why does this function accept char* pad and not char pad so I can do just pad it with '0', will "0" work too or does it add a null terminator screwing it up or something?

**EDIT**: Or can somebody provide a simple example (or what I need to do what) to pad left for this? This snippet does not appear to be all that good..

I was thinking of creating a chararray initialized to zero, then copying the binary after that, but how to make it work escaped me..

Comment: For starters, the malloc looks wrong - it should be allocating at least (padlen + 1) bytes.

Comment: Noted, makes me wonder if this code snippet is worth fixing.. my only other snippet to do this uses sprintf incorrectly :P.

Comment: F: The way you use this function is a memory leak. It returns a pointer to malloc'ed memory and you use the pointer as a parameter to `printf`. It's using the pointer as a temporary variable and now you have no way to `free` the memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"padded" points to the end of the string when you are returning it.

Comment: Don't forget to free the returned string after fixing the function.

Comment: I tried to do pointer arithmetic `padded -= lenpad + 1;` but that only displayed three zeros (no matter what the input), I am not sure what to do.

Comment: @eyalm: He can't free the memory in the example. The return value is used as an unnamed temporary in the printf call.

Comment: @John F I would suggest that you assign another pointer to the  string (just after the malloc) and return that instead, that way you don't need to do additional pointer arithmetics. I.e., char *ptr = padded;

Comment: @Plow, I believe that works now, but I forgot it pads right not left, man I'm getting stressed over this..

Comment: @John F: Did you also change your code to save the returned value from `string_pad` and then `free` the memory?

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I am scrapping the code actually.. I need it to pad left not right, this is a great excuse to tinker and learn better how to work with memory. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example implementation. It relies on the caller to manage and pass in the space where the padding will be performed.

```
char *PadLeft(char *bufBeg, size_t bufSize, char padChar)
{
    char *p = bufBeg;
    char *end = bufBeg + bufSize;

    while (p < end && isspace(*p))
    {
         *p = padChar;
         p++;
    }

    return bufBeg;
}
```

In action it would look like this...

```
char padArea[32 + 1];

snprintf(padArea, sizeof(padArea), "%*s", sizeof(padArea) - 1, dec2bin(~myInt));

PadLeft(padArea, sizeof(padArea), '0');
...
```

...or...

```
int padAreaSize = 32 + 1;

char *padArea = malloc(padAreaSize);

snprintf(padArea, padAreaSize, "%*s", padAreaSize - 1, dec2bin(~myInt));

PadLeft(padArea, padAreaSize, '0');

...

free(padArea);
```

(don't forget to add error checking, left out here for clarity)

A pad right function would be similar:

```
char *PadRight(char *bufBeg, size_t bufSize, char padChar)
{
    char *p = bufBeg + bufSize;

    while (--p >= bufBeg && isspace(*p))
    {
         *p = padChar;        
    }

    return bufBeg;
}

int padAreaSize = 32 + 1;

char *padArea = malloc(padAreaSize);

snprintf(padArea, padAreaSize, "%-*s", padAreaSize - 1, dec2bin(~myInt));

PadRight(padArea, padAreaSize, '0');

...

free(padArea);
```